# How to send a file via Axios to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I need to post a File from client to server via Axios.

Here is my Vuejs code :

```
methods: {
    'successUpload': function (file) {
        const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } };
        axios.post('/Upload/File',file, config).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        });
    }
}
```

And here is my Laravel code for handling sent file :

```
public function uploadFile(Request $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile('file'))
      return "It's a File";

    return "No! It's not a File";
}
```

But it always returns `No It's not a File`.

Any helps would be great appreciated.

Comment: Can you show how you're calling `successUpload`?

Comment: I'm using Dropzonejs for uploading files

Comment: Just an FYI, but if you're using dropzone you don't need to use axios for the file upload.

Comment: Please tell me how? with `url` attribute ?

Comment: It goes out of the scope of this question but if you open a new one and provide the code where actually initialise `Dropzone` I will happily help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to create a FormData object and append the image file.

```
methods: {
  'successUpload': function (file) {

    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', document.getElementById('file').files[0]);

    axios.post('/Upload/File',data).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    });
  }
}
```

An example is [here](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/blob/master/examples/upload/index.html).

Let me know if that works.