# Lumen file request returns an empty object

Tags: php, vue.js, axios, lumen, lumen-5.4

I'm using Vue + Axios and tried to submit file unto my Lumen app

HTML

```
<input type="file" ref="inputfile">
<input type="file" ref="inputfile2">
<button @click="submit">Submit</button>
```

Vue

```
methods : {
    submit(){
        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('listing_id',222);
        formData.append('listing_title','Listing Title');
        if( this.$refs.inputfile.value != '' ){
            formData.append('attachment',this.$refs.inputfile.files[0]);
        }
        if( this.$refs.inputfile2.value != '' ){
            formData.append('attachment2',this.$refs.inputfile2.files[0]);
        }


        axios.post(
            'https://api.domain.com/api/v3/claim',
            formData,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            }
        ).then(function(res){
            console.log(res);
        })

    }
}
```

and in my Lumen app

```
return response()->json([ 'success' => true, 'data' => $request->file('attachment') ]);
```

and the Lumen app just returns an empty object unexpectedly

[image]

I can confirm that there is a file request just by

```
$request->hasFile('attachment');
```

and it returns true, and also by

```
$request->file()
```

it returns me an array of empty objects.

I can validate also the `formData`  contents by doing so

```
formData.forEach(function(el){
    console.log(el.name);
});
```

and it returns me the file name of each attachment (without extra data from above fields).

What seems wrong or problem that file requests returns an empty object instead?

Comment: `file` will return an instance of [UploadedFile](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.0/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php) What do you want to return exactly?

Comment: @cbaconnier the problem is it simply showing an empty object {} so it returns undefined offset if I do $request->file()[0]->getClientOriginalName(); or return null if I do $request->file('attachment')->getClientOriginalName();

Comment: Your screenshot show `{success: false}` and you return a  `{success: true}` Is this normal? Otherwise, Do you get something with `logger($request->file('attachment')->getClientSize())` or `getMimeType()` ?

Comment: @cbaconnier dont mind the success, the column 'data' contains $request->file('attachment')

Comment: @cbaconnier doing so $request->file('attachment')->getClientSize() returns null because the file request simply empty. I have no idea

Comment: Did you try without the content type? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907747/how-to-send-a-file-via-axios-to-laravel

Comment: @cbaconnier no luck, still empty.

Comment: I can see you are returning `success => true`, yet in your response it is `success => false ` are you sure you get to the `return response()->json([ 'success' => true, 'data' => $request->file('attachment') ]);`