# pass the value of a uploaded file photo in vuejs and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want to upload my photo and pass the value to the laravel. I have this edit profile which my photo be uploaded. Now my problem is how will i able to pass the value of the photo to axios. Here is my code below

```
<template>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Profile Form</div>
         <div class="card-body">
            <div class="container">
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm">
                        <div v-show="updatePP" id="preview">
                            <img v-if="url" :src="url" />
                        </div>
                        <div v-show="pp" v-if="editProfile.profile_pic == NULL">
                             <img src="https://i.imgflip.com/4/d0tb7.jpg" />
                        </div>
                        <div v-else>
                             asasasas
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm">
                        <form @submit.prevent="formSubmit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-row" >
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <label>First Name:</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" v-model="editProfile.name" />  
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <label>Last Name:</label>
                                    <br>
                                   <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" class="form-control" v-model="editProfile.last_name" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <label>Address:</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="text" id="address" name="address" class="form-control" v-model="editProfile.address" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <label>Upload Profile:</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" @change="onFileChange" />
                                </div>
                               
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    
                                  
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Update</button>
                                </div>                   
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                       
                    </div>
                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
           
            
            editProfile:{
                userId: this.$userId,
            },
            
            url: null,
            pp: true,
            updatePP: false,
            userId:this.$userId,
        }
    },

    mounted(){
        const url = window.location.href;
        const id = url.split("/").slice(4)[0];
        this.getEditProfile(id);
    },
    methods:{
        onFileChange(e){
            const file = e.target.files[0];
            this.url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            this.editProfile.photo = file;

            this.updatePP = true;
            this.pp = false;
    
        },
        
        formSubmit(){
            const ids = this.userId;      
           
            let currentObj = this;

            alert(this.editProfile.name);
            alert(this.editProfile.last_name);
            alert(this.editProfile.address);
            alert(this.editProfile.photo.name);

            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('photo', this.editProfile.photo.name);
            formData.append('name', this.editProfile.name);
            formData.append('lastName', this.editProfile.last_name);
            formData.append('address', this.editProfile.address);
            console.log(formData.values);
            axios.put(`/api/profile/${ids}/update`, this.editProfile).then(response=>{
                console.log(response.data);
                currentObj.success = response.data.success;
               

            }).catch(error=>{
                console.log(error);
                currentObj.output = error;
            });
        },

        updateProfile(id){
           
        },
        
        getEditProfile(id){
           axios.get(`/api/profile/${id}/edit`).then(response=>{
                this.editProfile = response.data;
                console.log(response.data);
           });
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
    #preview {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    #preview img {
        max-width: 250px;
        max-height: 250px;
    }
</style>
```

i am using the `FormData()` and i want the data to be pass to axios.
Any help is muchly appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the file's input field and submit the `FormData` object you are creating.

Change your `submit()` function to something like this and HTML forms do not support `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` actions. So, when defining `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` routes that are called from an HTML form, you will need to sprrof it and add a hidden `_method` field to the form (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#form-method-spoofing):

```
formSubmit(){
            const ids = this.userId;      
           
            let currentObj = this;

            alert(this.editProfile.name);
            alert(this.editProfile.last_name);
            alert(this.editProfile.address);
            alert(this.editProfile.photo.name);

            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('photo', this.editProfile.photo.name);
            formData.append('name', this.editProfile.name);
            formData.append('lastName', this.editProfile.last_name);
            formData.append('address', this.editProfile.address);
            formData.append('file', document.getElementById('fileInputId').files[0]);
            console.log(formData.values);
            axios.post(`/api/profile/${ids}/update`, formData).then(response=>{
                console.log(response.data);
                currentObj.success = response.data.success;
               

            }).catch(error=>{
                console.log(error);
                currentObj.output = error;
            });
        },
```

Then to use `put`, add this to your form: `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">`.

In your controller you can check to see if the file came through successfully with something like:

```
public function controllerMethod(Request $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile('file')) {
      dd('Success - there is a file.');
   }

    dd('Unsuccessful - there is no file');
}
```

This questions may help: [How to send a file via Axios to Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42907747/4517964)

Comment: can you update your code? it seems its not working when i pass the formData to axios

Comment: how will i able to pass the formData to my Laravel

Comment: Hi why is my formData is empty when the data is passed tru laravel

Comment: Did you update your ```axios.put()``` to include the ```formData``` object instead of ```this.editProfile``` you were using before?

Comment: yes using your code in the comment axios.put(`/api/profile/${ids}/update`, formData)

Comment: others says the put in axios wont work instead use post. I will still to try that out

Comment: Yes I apologize, I did not notice that. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: okay i will check this over the weekends.