# Vuex+Laravel: Can't send multiple files with FormData and axios to server side. Always getting null on server side. What's going on?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios, vuex

The information which I got by my previous question [Vuex + Laravel. Why axios sends any values but only not that one, which come's with method's parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70188942/vuex-laravel-why-axios-sends-any-values-but-only-not-that-one-which-comes-w/70192480#70192480)
works only for situation when I pass only one argument in axios. I also found how to successfully pass multiple files with one argument, but in my situation, I have to use object, to be able to pass more than one argument. So instead of

```
const response = await axios.post('/posts', data)
```

I have to use the next one

```
const response = await axios.post('/posts', {
                formData:data,
                body:postBody
            })
```

I thought it would be easy, but now is the 5-th hour that I can't find the solution.

[image]

controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $files = $request->all();
        return var_dump($files);
    }
```

I tried many things, included $request->allFiles() and getClientOriginalExtension() experiments. No results.
What versions do you have? How this problem can be fixed?

Important!
I use Laravel, vuex, axios.
I use text not in FormData cause it's textArea. And if I can combinate textarea in FormData to make one argument axios call, anyway it still very important to me to know what's the problem which I described above.

Updated

Here's chrome's payload tab

[image]

Comment: Are you completely sure that files are sent to the endpoint? Could you share your request payload from chrome's dev console?

Comment: @Luciano no. It's just very strange. Without object method as a single argument everything works, but as object — Nothing. I updated the question. You can watch the screenshot you wanted.

Comment: Why don't you just send everything within formData object? Why would you want to send a formData and also data?

Comment: @Luciano as I see, it's not logically correct to send all data with only one FormData. Cause formData means data, which belongs to form context. Textarea maybe we can  take as a form data, but what if I want to send another data too?

Comment: Well, the short answer is "you can't". In terms of "logically correct" why would you send a `post` payload with some data that do not regard the post-action itself?

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty clear why you don't send everything you need within  `formData` object.

You could do something like:

```
const formData = new FormData()

formData.append(body, postBody)
formData.append(files, fileList)
formData.append(otherData, someOtherData)

const response = await axios.post('/posts', formData)
```

Then in your server side you will be able to do

```
 $body = $request->body;
 $files = $request->files;
 $otherData = $request->otherData;
```

Comment: That's helpful,, so I marked it as useful.